# What should I do about spam questions?

Tags: support, faq, spam

I keep seeing spam questions on the site. Usually about poker, for some reason. What should I do about those? They make me *angry*.  They make me want to **HULK SMASH**.

[Return to FAQ Index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970)

Answer (score 21):

**You should flag them!**

[image: links beneath the tags on a question: share / edit / close / flag]

Choose the ***spam*** reason, naturally.

[image: "spam: exists only to promote a product or service; does not disclose the author's affiliation."]

Don't:

- vote to close them; you're wasting your close votes.
- downvote it; flagging it as spam automatically downvotes it for you.

If you flag it (see the link right below the tags?) it'll come to a moderator's attention the next time they visit the site. Next to the link that takes us to the moderation tools, there's a little icon that shows moderators how many flags are in the system, so they always see flags immediately.

Also, if an item gets enough flags, it's *automagically deleted*!

If you feel like this isn't enough, comment and/or link it in chat suggesting other people flag the question.