# Spam user report

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam

I am reporting this spammer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/61952/tonyzega
Their about me is just spam for their product. Please do delete the user, and do not support that company that it is spamming for.

Comment: Related: [What should I do about spam questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-should-i-do-about-spam-questions)

Comment: @V2Blast That user is a spammer please delete _it_.

Comment: Related: [Simple way to report spammy users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36131/simple-way-to-report-spammy-users), [How do I deal with spam users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-do-i-deal-with-spam-users)

Comment: Spam users don't generally need to be reported individually, but it's been destroyed. Thanks!